# "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable " - Numpy Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Here is my code.

```
def h(x, theta):                      # this is probability/hypotheses
    return np.dot(x, theta)


def cost(x, y, theta):                    # this is cost function
    m = x.shape[0]
    hypothesis = h(x, theta)
    error = hypothesis - y
    return 1 / (2 * m) * (np.dot(error.T, error))    # (1/2m)*sum[(error)^2]
```

I have a function "h" which is calculating dot products of 2 matrices. and it is working as expected.
I tested it and here is output

```
print("x.shape = ", x.shape)                         # x.shape =  (97, 2)
print("theta.shape =", theta.shape)                  # theta.shape = (2, 1)
print("my_hypothesis.shape =",  my_hypothesis.shape) # my_hypothesis.shape = (97, 1)
```

But when i am calling function "h" from with-in "cost" function. 
hypothesis = h(x, theta)
I am getting error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

If i replace line hypothesis = h(x, theta) with hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta) then it is working fine.

Please let me what wrong i am doing?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't redefined `h` somewhere in your code? This looks like a typo to me, one that involves code that you haven't shown. Also, why not simply `h = np.dot` ? Functions are first-class citizens in Python -- you can directly assign them to variables.

Comment: Also, you say that " I tested it [referring to `h`] and here is output" but then proceed to give three lines that don't even mention `h`. How do those 3 lines constitute a test of `h`? Please provide a [mcve]. There seem to be relevant things which you are not showing us.

Comment: Here is code https://github.com/amitsuneja/MachineLeaning/blob/master/AndrewNG/Week2/Week2-LinearRegressionSingleVariable.py

Comment: Here is Data i am using in this code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amitsuneja/MachineLeaning/master/AndrewNG/Week2/ex1data1.txt

Comment: I am getting same error again when i run j_list, theta_list, hypothesis = batch_gradient_descent(x, y, theta, alpha)

Comment: can you copy paste the code and data file and try to reproduce error please

Comment: But -- that isn't the code you posted. Please edit your question so that it contains code that has the property that when someone (who has `numpy` installed) runs it, they will get the error that you are getting. I can't replicate the error. What is the actual stack trace? There is a chance that you have misinterpreted it and are attaching it to a different line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue , i just this statement

`return (alpha * (1 / m) * (np.dot(error.T, x))).T`

Below is link of working code.

https://github.com/amitsuneja/MachineLeaning/blob/master/AndrewNG/Week2/Excercise01/Week2-LinearRegressionSingleVariable.py